# Steps to create facebook friend list using facebook api

Tags: android, facebook

Suggest me the steps to create Facebook friends list in Android application using **Facebook API** please

Comment: did you try something on yourself ?

Comment: this is not the place to ask for code straight. You have to try something on yourself first

Comment: i am also tried but something is wrong so i don't understand what problem occurred,please suggest me

Comment: "something" is wrong? what is "something"? do you get any errors? what have you tried? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: There was no error but that can't show my facebook friends list in listview and return same page after login

Comment: you need to edit your question and include the code. don´t post part of your question as answer.

Comment: Please suggest me what can  we do for getting friends list in listview in android application

Comment: i use that code but noone  friends list  shown in my application.I dont know what exactly we do for getting Facebook friends list in listview

Comment: I still can't see your code...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to authorize with the `user_friends` permission to get friends.

That being said, it´s not possible to get all friends anymore, /me/friends only returns friends who authorized your App too. More details can be found in the answer of this thread: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Also, `publish_stream` is deprecated since many years. If you want to post to the user wall, use `publish_actions`.